# css selector for dynamic MuiButton-label

Tags: typescript, css-selectors, playwright, playwright-java

I am trying to find a selector for this date element, it is found as MuiButton-label but the date text is dynamic, I can locate using the xpath in the playwright code but looking for a way to locate it using a css selector. Appreciate your time and help.

[image]

with .MuiButton-label class selector it narrows down to 4 elements, however the text cannot be sued to pinpoint to date as it would change I am looking for a way other than regex :
[image]

Comment: Are the other matches for `.MuiButton-label` other dates below that dropdown or are they elsewhere in the page?

Comment: @AJG 
Date, Filter and Add appointments are 3 different button classes if I am getting your question right

Comment: it is hard to say really because I can't see what ancestors the other matches for `.MuiButton-label` have.  Might be worth a try seeing what playwright codgen comes up with: `npx playwright codgen https://your-url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could locate the element with this selector

```
button >> nth=3>>span>span:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this selector:

```
.MuiButton-label span:nth-child(2)
```

Explanation of selector:

- `.MuiButton-label`: An element with class "MuiButton-label"
- `span`: Sub elements of previous element with tag "span"
- `:nth-child(2)`: We will get 2 span, so we get the second one

Comment: hi thanks for the help, with .MuiButton-label span:nth-child(2) it could narrow down to 2 elements, extending that logic I could pinpoint the date with:
button >> nth = 3 >> span>span:nth-child(2). 
again thank you very much for the time and help